# Please criticise my code, trying to capture unlimited input from stdin

Tags: c, input, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

So this code will sometimes work and sometimes throw a "the impossible happened" error. As far as I can tell it seems to be caused by the way in which I'm realloc'ing memory for the string as it's parsed.

```
char* unlimInput() {
   char* input;
   int counter = 0;
   int buffer = 16;
   char c;
   do {
      c = getchar();
      if (counter +2 >= buffer) {
         int newSize = buffer * 2;
         char* newString = realloc(input, newSize);
         newString[counter] = c;
         buffer = newSize;
         input = newString;
      } else {
         input[counter] = c;
      }
      counter += 1;
   } while (c != '\n');
   return input;
}
```

I've been trying really hard to understand dynamic memory allocation so any pointers (no pun intended) would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to tag your question with the programming language you're using.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery My bad, fixed now.

Comment: What is the *exact* error you're getting? Please don't approximate.

Comment: You're using a lot of throw-away single-use variables here for no reason. `buffer *= 2` and `input = realloc(input, buffer)` should do the job, presuming you don't care about allocation failures.

Comment: There are several considerations. First, you have no way to return the length, so the caller will need to scan for the `'\0'` again. You must check the return of each allocation. You must handle `EOF` -- otherwise you keep spinning away looking for `'\n'`after `EOF` is encountered. [See function fgetcline()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687928/3422102) in this answer for several additional considerations. (note the code reads from `stdin` by default if no filename is given as an argument)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is sound. Good job. You just forgot to add the **null delimiter at the end of the string**. Write this line of code after the *getchar() function* :

```
*(input+counter)='\0';
```

Then you will return a valid string.

Well I hope my answer was helpful to you. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Instead of reposting the answer to get rid of the downvotes (without even fixing the problems in it!), you could fix the existing one, and `@notify` the downvoter (me, in this case) so they can remove their downvote.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I checked it just now...you don't need a cast. So I think a downvote is necessary. Thanks though :)

Comment: Consider fixing the answer then. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is this fine?

Comment: *Your code is sound* when not in an excetional state, but +1 for a clear answer.